# How to search the string using UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the test.txt file,which contain below data inside the file.

```
Cat test.txt
BG BEGIN BS JOB
OPERATOR:  BICJobname
Select EMP_NAME ,salary,dep_name from EMP_Table Where DEP_ID=101
END BS JOB
BG BEGIN BS JOB
OPERATOR:  BICJobname1   
Select EMP_NAME ,salary from EMP_Table1 Where DEP_ID=102 
END BS JOB
BG BEGIN BS JOB
OPERATOR:  BICJobname3
Select EMP_NAME from EMP_Table2 Where DEP_ID=102
END BS JOB
BG BEGIN BS JOB
OPERATOR:  BICJobname5
Select EMP_NAME,Date_Of_Joining,Salary from EMP_Table3 Where DEP_ID=101
END BS JOB
BG BEGIN BS JOB
OPERATOR:  BICJobname6
Select EMP_NAME,Date_Of_Joining,Salary from EMP_Table3 Where DEP_ID=101
END BS JOB
```

My Question :- If i searched the column name(string as salary) in the above file i need to get the job name which is having salary fileds.

o/p

```
Job Name
BICJobname1    salary
BICJobname3     No
BICJobname5    Salary
BICJobname6    Salary
```

Comment: Do it using `awk`. When you read the `OPERATOR:` line, get the second word into a variable, then read the next line and test whether it contains `salary`.

Comment: yup ..i can achieve that through awk ..how search in loop for next time i am confused there..i am not getting how to loop for each begin and end of the job and collect the information..

Comment: Just use `/OPERATOR:/` tomatch the operator lines. Then use `getline` to read the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` to match the `OPERATOR:` lines, then read the next line with `getline` to see if it has salary or not.

```
awk '/OPERATOR:/ { job = $2; getline; 
                    if (tolower($0) ~ /salary/) sal = "Salary"; else sal = "No"; 
                    print job, sal }'
```